# How to dynamically change Content of Push Notification (FCM) in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working in a project that requires me to send dynamic push notification to the app client based on Firebase Database. So whenever there is a update in the database I need to send FCM based on that updated content. I've read several forums about it but ended up in conclusion that we need an app server. Is there any way to do it only using Firebase? Maybe by utilizing Firebase "Function" feature?